# Filter Columns in a Table based on Data Type

Tags: sql

Table name:  **Table1**

```
Name             DataType
PK_tablekey        INT
FK_Table2Keu       INT
CreateTime       datetime
DateField1       datetime
DateField2       datetime
Createdby        NVARCHAR(32)
Name1             NVARCHAR(32)
Flag             BIT
Value1           Decimal(19,4)
Value2           Decimal(19,4)
```

I want to query only these field out of that using over by clause

```
DateField1       datetime
DateField2       datetime
Name1            NVARCHAR(32)
Flag             BIT
Value1           Decimal(19,4)
Value2           Decimal(19,4)
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION ASC)) AS ColumnNumber,
    CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS NVARCHAR(150)) AS ColumnName    
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME = N'Table1'
    AND DATA_TYPE IN ( N'decimal') 

UNION ALL                      

SELECT  
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION ASC)) AS ColumnNumber,
    CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS NVARCHAR(150)) AS ColumnName     
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME = N'Table1'
    AND DATA_TYPE IN (N'nvarchar')
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Name1 '  

UNION ALL                         

SELECT  
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION ASC)) AS ColumnNumber,
    CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS datetime) AS ColumnName,
    CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS datetime) AS OverwriteColumnName
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME = N'Table1'
    AND DATA_TYPE IN (N'datetime')
    AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('DateField1', 'DateField2')
```

It does not seem to work when this proc is called it throws an error message

> Request failed: Invalid column name : DateField1
>   Request failed: Invalid column name: DateField2

Also I want to add the BIT column as well .

Can anyone help me would be nice if the query is short  as i use the UNION ALL.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results you want to get.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use rownumber, its SQL Server.

First, your query has errors: all unions must have same columns to be returned. Your 3rd union returns 3 columns instead of required two.

If you need to order your data, you can try this:

```
SELECT
     [ColumnNumber] 
    ,[ColumnName]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
         [ColumnNumber] = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION ASC))
        ,[ColumnName]   = CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS NVARCHAR(150)) 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Table1'
        AND DATA_TYPE IN ( N'decimal') 

    UNION ALL                      

    SELECT  
         [ColumnNumber] =  (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION ASC))
        ,[ColumnName]   =  CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS NVARCHAR(150))
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Table1'
        AND DATA_TYPE IN (N'Name1')
        AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Name1 '  

    UNION ALL                         

    SELECT  
         [ColumnNumber] = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION ASC)) 
        ,[ColumnName]   =  CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS datetime) 
        --  , CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS datetime) AS OverwriteColumnName  --you need 2 cols, not 3!
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Table1'
        AND DATA_TYPE IN (N'datetime')
        AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('DateField1','DateField2')
) AS [r]
ORDER BY
     [r].[ColumnNumber]
    ,[r].[ColumnName];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this?

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATA_TYPE ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION ASC) AS ColumnNumber,
       CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS NVARCHAR(150)) AS ColumnName  
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Table1' AND
      DATA_TYPE IN ( N'decimal', N'datetime', N'Name1') ;
```

Instead of `DATA_TYPE`, you might want to specify the columns that you do want.  The key idea is `PARTITION BY`.